# Gcc do not give warning about newline of end of file

Tags: c, gcc

I tried to code a well known hello world program in c and compiled it using this command :

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 main.c -o exeFile
```

but I did not get any warning about  5.1.1.2 in C standard (newline at end of file).

I used Vim editor for that and I has also disabled newline settings by typing:

```
set binary 
set noeol
```

I want to know how can I generate this warning.

used GCC: 5.4.0

This is the source file :

[image]

This is the output of compiler:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about *A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such splicing takes place.*?

Comment: yes I am talking about that.

Comment: If you used GCC 5.4.0, then surely the documentation for that version would be a more appropriate resource than the docs for an earlier version.  Either way, it would be helpful if you provided a more specific citation to the GCC docs, to facilitate reviewing the passage in context.

Comment: You'll see that if you don't have a newline as the last character of a file.  The warning spells out what it is.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, the OP seems to be claiming that she does not get a warning, even though she expects one.

Comment: I thought if  I include `-std` and `pedantic` the compiler will behave according to ISO standard C.

Comment: @Sabrina, rather than simply rely on your editor's options to have done what you expect, it would be best to examine the actual source file you're building.  You can do this with vim most clearly by switching to hex editing, as described [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/343/how-to-edit-binary-files-with-vim).  I'm guessing you'll find that there is a newline after all, but either way, the details will provide a firmer basis for the question.

Comment: The last character in the file is \x7d which is 125 refering to the last brace  `}`. Sorry I don't have more rating than you so you can believe me

Comment: @Sabrina: can you post the source code?

Comment: OK. I have the same lack of warning with `gcc 4.7.2` on an old Debian system, but I do get the warning with `clang-700.0.72` on OS/X.  Quality of implementation issue.

Comment: So i.e. clang is better for compilation.

Comment: There is no such warning in GCC.  Look here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html.  Good question ... but I STRONGLY object to drawing a stupid conclusion like "so clang is better for compilation". GCC is a usually *superb* choice.  So, for many other use cases, is Microsoft C - which may or may not give a warning.

Comment: You cannot draw this conclusion from this simplistic test alone!  Would you say NYC is safer than LA because the town hall elevators make audible announcements for the basement floors in one and not the other?

Comment: I want to see the warning what should I do ?

Comment: If you insist on seeing a warning for this, use clang.

Comment: thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This was a deliberate decision made in the GCC 4.3.2 timeframe, and carried forward to subsequent releases:

[WONTFIX Bug 40474 - gcc 4.3 no longer warns about missing newlines at end of files](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40474)

[RESOLVED Bug 14331 - please add option to suppress warning message "no newline at end of file"](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14331)

Comment: In that case the program will be considered as UB or ??

Comment: If it was going to make it UB, the compiler would warn. It's a non- issue to GCC.

Comment: Okay is the program considered as UB when omitting the newline at eof ?

Comment: It is still UB according to the C standard, but GCC has chosen to define the behavior.  (There are many other such cases.)  The program is _conforming_, because there exists at least one implementation that translates it as the programmer intended, but it is not _strictly conforming_, because it relies on what one particular implementation does in this case of standard-undefined behavior.